# Android How to setup specific Densitys for Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I have defined the width and height of a low density screen on my emulator, but all of the images and text are now just huge.

Is there a way to define what density the emulator should be?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the AVD property **Abstracted LCD density** to the desired value.

Comment: what should the values be for Low, Medium and High. I can't seem to find examples in the documentation

Comment: you can use 120, 160, 240 and 320

Answer (score 0):

Within the Android SDK and AVD Manager, select your desired virtual device and choose edit.  Resolution can be determined under the Skin: section, and the density can be by adding in a value for Abstracted LCD density under the Hardware: section.